# Why are the DOM elements not being selected

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I have a function that shows an html element when hovered upon, but it does not seem to be working as intended.

My code in the js file is as follows:

```
const htmlIc = document.querySelector('.fa-html5');
const htmlInfo = document.querySelector('.info-section');

htmlIc.addEventListener("mouseover", toggleHtml);


function toggleHtml() {
       htmlInfo.classList.add("show");
}
```

This is the element that the event listener is listening upon (the icon):

```
<div class="icons">
     <a href="#!">
         <i class="fab fa-html5 fa-2x"></i>
     </a>
</div>
```

This is the element I would like to have the show class applied to:

```
<div class="info-section">
     <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
</div>
```

I use SASS in this project, and I have verified by manually adding the show class to the element, and it is not a problem from that part

Comment: Any errors in browser dev tools console?

Comment: this try htmlInfo.classList.toggle("show");

Comment: The code looks ok. I guess the issue is with the placement of the `script` tag. Where have you placed the script in the html?

Comment: @PraneetDixit I placed It at the very bottom, above the body tag

Comment: @BerkCoşar YESS!!! Finally!!! Ive been working on this issue for about 2 days now!

Comment: @JaydenLeuciuc then I think it's another issue. Do you see any error in the browser console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
htmlInfo.classList.toggle("show");
```

I just had to use the .toggle method for the classList. Since I was using a hover effect, the toggle was more suited for this situation. Credit goes to @BerkCoşar in the comments for this solution

Answer (score 0):

You can do something where you are toggling them via the `style` `display` option. One thing you could do is if you are married to using `show` class then you would need to create a similar toggle between displaying show and hide.

```js
const htmlIc = document.querySelector(".fa-html5");
const htmlInfo = document.querySelector(".info-section");

htmlIc.addEventListener("mouseover", toggleHtml);

function toggleHtml() {
  let infoSection = document.querySelector(".info-section");
  if (infoSection.style.display === "none") {
    infoSection.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    infoSection.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="icons">
      <a href="#!">
        <i class="fab fa-html5 fa-2x">hh</i>
      </a>
      <div class="info-section" style="display: none;">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

it's work!
also add .show css class

```js
const htmlIc = document.querySelector('.fa-html5');
const htmlInfo = document.querySelector('.info-section');

htmlIc.addEventListener("mouseover", toggleHtml);

function toggleHtml() {
       htmlInfo.classList.add("show");
}
```

```html
<div class="icons">
     <a href="#!">
         <i class="fab fa-html5 fa-2x"></i>
     </a>
</div>
<div class="info-section">
     <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
</div>
```